# how to combine those hover functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have many of spans whitch i need to group to change opacity after hover, all of them need to have unique IDs, is there a way to combine all those hover functions to one function ??

jQuery

```
//09    
    $('#c_09_241a, #c_09_241b, #c_09_241c, #c_09_241d').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_09_241a, #c_09_241b, #c_09_241c, #c_09_241d').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_09_241a, #c_09_241b, #c_09_241c, #c_09_241d').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    }); 
    $('#c_09_242a, #c_09_242b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_09_242a, #c_09_242b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_09_242a, #c_09_242b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_09_245a, #c_09_245b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_09_245a, #c_09_245b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_09_245a, #c_09_245b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_09_246a, #c_09_246b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_09_246a, #c_09_246b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_09_246a, #c_09_246b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });

    //08    
    $('#c_08_235a, #c_08_235b, #c_08_235c, #c_08_235d').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_08_235a, #c_08_235b, #c_08_235c, #c_08_235d').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_08_235a, #c_08_235b, #c_08_235c, #c_08_235d').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    }); 
    $('#c_08_236a, #c_08_236b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_08_236a, #c_08_236b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_08_236a, #c_08_236b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_08_239a, #c_08_239b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_08_239a, #c_08_239b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_08_239a, #c_08_239b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_08_240a, #c_08_240b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_08_240a, #c_08_240b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_08_240a, #c_08_240b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });

    //07    
    $('#c_07_227a, #c_07_227b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_07_227a, #c_07_227b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_07_227a, #c_07_227b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_07_228a, #c_07_228b, #c_07_228c').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_07_228a, #c_07_228b, #c_07_228c').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_07_228a, #c_07_228b, #c_07_228c').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_07_007a, #c_07_007b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_07_007a, #c_07_007b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_07_007a, #c_07_007b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
    $('#c_07_008a, #c_07_008b').hover(
        function() {
            $('#c_07_008a, #c_07_008b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
        },
        function() {
             $('#c_07_008a, #c_07_008b').stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="rzuty09p" class="rzuty">
            <span id="c_09_241a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_241b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_241c" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_241d" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_242a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_242b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_243" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_244" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_245a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_245b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_246a" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_09_246b" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
        </div>  

<div id="rzuty08p" class="rzuty">
            <span id="c_08_235a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_235b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_235c" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_235d" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_236a" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_236b" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_237" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_238" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_239a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_239b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_240a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_08_240b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
        </div>      

<div id="rzuty07p" class="rzuty">
            <span id="c_07_226" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_227a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_227b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_228a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_228b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_228c" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_229" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_005" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_006" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_007a" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_007b" class="mieszkanie nie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_008a" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
            <span id="c_07_008b" class="mieszkanie" title=""></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Add a general class to the `span`s that need the same effect, and make jQuery selectorwith that class?

Comment: $(".rzuty > span").each(...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx to Matt, we have the final answer

```
var ids = [
    "#c_07_227a, #c_07_227b",
    "#c_07_228a, #c_07_228b, #c_07_228c"
    // add more here
];

ids.forEach(function(i) {
    $(i).hover(function() {
        $(i).stop(true, true).css('opacity', '1');
    }, function() {
        $(i).stop(true, true).css('opacity', '0');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have three options:

1. Use your class as a selctor:

   ```
   $('.mieszkanie').hover(
       function() {
           $(this).stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
       },
       function() {
           $(this).stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
   });
   ```
2. Add all the IDs in the same selector:

   ```
   $('#c_09_245a, #c_09_245b, #c_09_246a, #c_09_246b, #c_09_247a, #c_09_247b').hover(
       function() {
           $(this).stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
       },
       function() {
           $(this).stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
   });
   ```
3. Make two functions that do the required thing to reduce your code:

   ```
   function show () {
       $(this).stop(true, true).css('opacity','1');
   }

   function hide () {
       $(this).stop(true, true).css('opacity','0');
   }

   $(selector).hover(show, hide);
   ```

Comment: @Robert K, thanks, I didn't know that. I was already struggling with the formatting :).

Comment: No problem; I looked at the documentation to see if it was possible—and lo, and behold... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` inside most jQuery event handlers that carries the element that triggered the event. Try something like:

```
$('.rzuty>span').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).css('opacity',1);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).css('opacity',0);
});
```

Or if you want to be more specific, add a class and use it in the selector.